# How to fix the fa fa phone icon section using bootstrap

Tags: html, css

[image: this is how it is looking from the below ode][image]

This is the design what I am doing, I have done each and everything correct but unable to fix the last section that is fa fa phone icon section.

```
                    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
                    <html>
                    <head>
                    <title>Web app design & Development</title>
                    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
                    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                    </head>

                    <body style="background:#e1e1d0">

                        <div>
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="banner.jpg" alt="banner Image" width="100%" height="500px">
                        </div>

                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <h3 style="font-size:50px"><span style="color:#cc7a00; margin-left:15px"><b>Business</b></span> <span style="color:#0f7abd"><b>Solution</b></span></h3>
                                    <p  style="font-size:28px; margin-top:-20px; margin-left:60px">that will help you out in disaterous state.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div><br>

                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <p><span style="color:#0f7abd;font-size:20px; margin-left:10px"><b>Business</b></span> <span style="color:#cc7a00;font-size:20px"><b>Alliances</b></span></p>
                                    <p class="text-justify" style="color:#afaf83;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus interdum erat libero, pulvinar tincidunt leo consectetur eget. Curabitur lacinia pellentesque libero, pulvinar tincidunt leo consectetur eget. Curabitur lacinia pellentesque libero,
                                    pulvinar tincidunt leo consectetur eget. Curabitur lacinia pellentesqueLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus interdum erat libero, pulvinar tincidunt leo consectetur eget. Curabitur lacinia pellentesque libero, pulvinar tincidunt leo consectetur eget. Curabitur lacinia pellentesque libero,
                                    pulvinar tincidunt leo consectetur eget. Curabitur lacinia pellentesque </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4" style="padding-left:45px">
                                    <p><span style="color:#0f7abd;font-size:20px"><b>Support</b></span> <span style="color:#cc7a00;font-size:20px"><b>Alliances</b></span></p>
                                    <p>
                                        <span style="color:#0f7abd"><b>&#10004;</b></span> <span style="color:#afaf83; margin-left:15px">Loremei ipeisum is simplye meto ply</span><br>
                                        <span style="color:#0f7abd"><b>&#10004;</b></span> <span style="color:#afaf83; margin-left:15px">Loremei ipeisum is simplye meto ply</span><br>
                                        <span style="color:#0f7abd"><b>&#10004;</b></span> <span style="color:#afaf83; margin-left:15px">Loremei ipeisum is simplye meto ply</span><br>
                                        <span style="color:#0f7abd"><b>&#10004;</b></span> <span style="color:#afaf83; margin-left:15px">Loremei ipeisum is simplye meto ply</span>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-8">

                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-1" style="padding-left:45px">
                                    <i class="fa fa-phone" style="font-size:35px; color:#ffffff; width:35px; height:35px;border-radius:4px;background-color:#0f7abd;text-align: center;"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-3" style="margin-top:-8px">
                                    <p><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none"><span style="color:#cc7a00; font-size:23px"><b>(098)-2304-5678</b></span><br><span style="color:#0f7abd; padding-left:42px">www.weloreorm.com</span></a></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div><br>
                    </body>
                    </html>
```

The above code is what I have tried with but I'm unable to fix the issue.

I'm trying to fix the issue from morning but unable to do. So please help me to solve the issue.

Thank you.
 the first image is the image whih i did and the seond image is the image how i need so please an any one tel me how an i fix the issuue fa fa phone icon issue

Comment: You haven't told us what the issue is. Please also reduce your code to a [MCVE]

Comment: Also separate out the *inline* css to a proper CSS stylesheet.

Comment: @Paulie_D ya i will seperate out the inline css. I have ompleted the work but not exactly how the design is

Answer (score -1):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
                    <html>
                    <head>
                    <title>Web app design & Development</title>
                    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
                    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                    </head>

                    <body style="background:#e1e1d0">

                        <div>
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="banner.jpg" alt="banner Image" width="100%" height="500px">
                        </div>

                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <h3 style="font-size:50px"><span style="color:#cc7a00; margin-left:15px"><b>Business</b></span> <span style="color:#0f7abd"><b>Solution</b></span></h3>
                                    <p  style="font-size:28px; margin-top:-20px; margin-left:60px">that will help you out in disaterous state.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div><br>

                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <p><span style="color:#0f7abd;font-size:20px; margin-left:10px"><b>Business</b></span> <span style="color:#cc7a00;font-size:20px"><b>Alliances</b></span></p>
                                    <p class="text-justify" style="color:#afaf83;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus interdum erat libero, pulvinar tincidunt leo consectetur eget. Curabitur lacinia pellentesque libero, pulvinar tincidunt leo consectetur eget. Curabitur lacinia pellentesque libero,
                                    pulvinar tincidunt leo consectetur eget. Curabitur lacinia pellentesqueLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus interdum erat libero, pulvinar tincidunt leo consectetur eget. Curabitur lacinia pellentesque libero, pulvinar tincidunt leo consectetur eget. Curabitur lacinia pellentesque libero,
                                    pulvinar tincidunt leo consectetur eget. Curabitur lacinia pellentesque </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4" style="padding-left:45px">
                                    <p><span style="color:#0f7abd;font-size:20px"><b>Support</b></span> <span style="color:#cc7a00;font-size:20px"><b>Alliances</b></span></p>
                                    <p>
                                        <span style="color:#0f7abd"><b>&#10004;</b></span> <span style="color:#afaf83; margin-left:15px">Loremei ipeisum is simplye meto ply</span><br>
                                        <span style="color:#0f7abd"><b>&#10004;</b></span> <span style="color:#afaf83; margin-left:15px">Loremei ipeisum is simplye meto ply</span><br>
                                        <span style="color:#0f7abd"><b>&#10004;</b></span> <span style="color:#afaf83; margin-left:15px">Loremei ipeisum is simplye meto ply</span><br>
                                        <span style="color:#0f7abd"><b>&#10004;</b></span> <span style="color:#afaf83; margin-left:15px">Loremei ipeisum is simplye meto ply</span>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-8">

                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-1" style="padding-left:45px">
                                    <i class="fa fa-phone" style="font-size:35px; color:#ffffff; width:35px; height:35px;border-radius:4px;background-color:#0f7abd;position: relative; left: 30px;text-align: center;"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-3" style="margin-top:-8px">
                                    <p><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none"><span style="color:#cc7a00; font-size:23px"><b>(098)-2304-5678</b></span><br><span style="color:#0f7abd; padding-left:42px">www.weloreorm.com</span></a></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div><br>
                    </body>
                    </html>
```

use **position: realtive; left: 30px** at the fa fa-phone **style** tag